# freebsd i2c devices /dev/iicN ido not exist

Tags: drivers, freebsd

I am porting Linux program `ddcutil` to FreeBSD. On Linux, it reads from and writes to `/dev/i2c-N` devices, which are the video card I2C buses and exposed by the `i2c-dev` driver.

On FreeBSD, my understanding is that the corresponding devices are named `/dev/iicN` (see [iic(4)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=iic&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD+12.1-RELEASE+and+Ports))
and are exposed by the [`iicbus`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=iicbus&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD+12.1-RELEASE+and+Ports) driver. I have loaded i2c drivers `iicbus.ko`, `iic.ko`, and video driver `nvidia.ko`, but the devices do not exist. What am I missing?

The kldstat output:

```
root@ritter:/ # kldstat
Id Refs Address                Size Name
 1   56 0xffffffff80200000  2448d90 kernel
 2    1 0xffffffff8264a000  134d1e0 nvidia.ko
 3    6 0xffffffff83998000     9698 linux_common.ko
 4    2 0xffffffff839a2000    b7bd8 linux.ko
 5    1 0xffffffff83a5a000     3910 iic.ko
 6    2 0xffffffff83a5e000     6da0 iicbus.ko
 7    1 0xffffffff83c21000     494c linprocfs.ko
 8    1 0xffffffff83c26000     1eae linsysfs.ko
 9    1 0xffffffff83c28000     88d8 tmpfs.ko
10    1 0xffffffff83c31000     18a0 uhid.ko  
11    1 0xffffffff83c33000     2928 ums.ko
12    1 0xffffffff83c36000     1aa0 wmt.ko
13    1 0xffffffff83c38000    35b20 linux64.ko
```

Answer (score 0):

The necessary drivers for `i2c` / `iic` buses should be already part of your FreeBSD, as they have been a part of it since `FreeBSD 10.0-Stable`.

However, I can already see that you are missing

`iicbb`  - the generic bit-banging driver
`iicsmb`  - I2C to SMB bridge

When building your kernel, please check your kernel configuration file for your kernel for both smbus and i2c device drivers:

```
     device smbus
     device smb
     device iicbus
     device iicbb
     device iic
     device iicsmb
```

Afterwards, you should see `iic*` devices in the `dmesg | grep iic` output

Comment: All the drivers listed are specified in my loader.conf and are reported by kldstat.  Still no iic in dmesg

Comment: Could you post your new current full `kldstat` output (through pastebin if its too long for this stack). The above list I provided only allows for I/O operations on the I2C, but nothing in the list actually enumerates the I2C devices. In the Linux kernel, I2C devices - unlike PCI/USB - are not auto enumerated at hardware level, but instead the kernel is "told" about them, these days through ACPI (conversion to devicetree). Some i2c devices may not be added at boot (temp sensors), but handlers for probing and many i2c drivers are built into the kernel.

Comment: If you look at any of the i2c graphics driver files in the linux kernel that handle DDC/CI, for example for Nvidia `nv_i2c.c`, you can see how the enumeration happens through `nvidia_probe_i2c_connector` (which uses fb_ddc_read on the DDC designated address of `0x50`), followed by `nvidia_create_i2c_buses`

Comment: Here's the kldstat output: https://pastebin.com/ppE0FaZt

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Thanks, could you also provide the version of both your Nvidia driver and the FreeBSD kernel with `pkg info nvidia-driver` and `uname -mrs`

Comment: Here it is: https://pastebin.com/bgBY3Lsi